# C++ member variables are not initialized when using a debug version static library

Tags: c++, constructor, visual-studio-2019, static-libraries, cesiumjs

- Environment: Windows10, cpp17, visual studio 2019, debug version static library

Recently I tried to use Cesium-Native to read 3DTiles files in my project, but there was a confusing problem that some member variables are not initialized correctly.
As following codes show, Tileset() use initializer list to initialize its member variables, but some of them like`_loadsInProgress`,`_previousFrameNumber` are initialized to random value which shoule have been 0. However some of them are initialize correctly like `_url`, `_options`, and it works well in Release Library and the same code in its original project. What a strange bug!

```
Tileset::Tileset(
    const TilesetExternals& externals,
    const std::string& url,
    const TilesetOptions& options)
    : _externals(externals),
      _asyncSystem(externals.asyncSystem),
      _userCredit(
          (options.credit && externals.pCreditSystem)
              ? std::optional<Credit>(externals.pCreditSystem->createCredit(
                    options.credit.value(),
                    options.showCreditsOnScreen))
              : std::nullopt),
      _url(url),
      _isRefreshingIonToken(false),
      _options(options),
      _pRootTile(),
      _previousFrameNumber(0),
      _loadsInProgress(0),
      _subtreeLoadsInProgress(0),
      _overlays(*this),
      _tileDataBytes(0),
      _supportsRasterOverlays(false),
      _gltfUpAxis(CesiumGeometry::Axis::Y),
      _distancesStack(),
      _nextDistancesVector(0) {
  if (!url.empty()) {
    CESIUM_TRACE_USE_TRACK_SET(this->_loadingSlots);
    this->notifyTileStartLoading(nullptr);
    LoadTilesetDotJson::start(*this, url).thenInMainThread([this]() {
      this->notifyTileDoneLoading(nullptr);
    });
  }
}
```

Through debugging, I found that _loadsInProgress was 0 at first, and it changes when a vector construct function is called. Maybe it's because generation of debug static lib?

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: What does it change to? 0xcc or 0xcd?

Comment: ***Maybe it's because generation of debug static lib?*** I would expect a bug in your code somewhere would be more likely than a build issue or a compiler bug.

Comment: This is hardly a minimal example, and it's certainly not complete.

Comment: You cannot link together a debug version of a static lib with a release version of an app/another static lib. Everything should be build with the same settings that go into a single executable.

Comment: @drescherjm it changes to a random value like `0xe4ff3a10`, which seems like a block of memory just allocated. And this is their libray code, my code actually are very short. But I really don't understand why constructor don't initialize member variables correctly

Comment: @MikeVine Thank you! I carefully check every setting of project and I found there is only different dir of `AdditionalIncludeDirectories`. So I change my project include dir to their native project include dir, and it works correctly. Then I change to my original include dir again, OMG it still works correctly.

Comment: The problem that have plagued me for days solved. In all, at first I used the different library version for `inlucde` and `lib` files, then I found that, I change the same version library include files to my project. But due to VS cache and the same file name(I guess), the change failed to apply to my project actually. I should have been found it early, because there is the args number of a virtual function changes for two different version. But I didnt realize it. Thank you all guys for enthusiastic comments!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by carefully checking all setting in running correctly original project and my project. And try to clean Visual Studio Cache and rebuild project and lib may be helpful for the problem.

At first I used the different library version for inlucde and lib files, then I found that, I change the same version library include files to my project. But due to VS cache and the same file name(I guess), the change failed to apply to my project actually.